# How to set default distance in Visio?

Tags: microsoft-visio

When I am placing objects one near another, Visio snaps to some irrational distance. How to set it to rational or integer number of grid units?

On picture below it is seen that Visio tends to place object at a distance approx 1.47 of grid units.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It's your horizontal spacing options that are one source for the dynamic grid (the yellow lines).  Have a look under the Design tab / Layout group and play around with the values there:

[image: Spacing options]